# Why below two programs gives conceptually different outputs?

Tags: java

**Please run output of below two programs...**

**Program_1:**

```
package p1;

class x {
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("Methos A of Class X");

    }
}

class y extends x {
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("Method A of Class Y");
    }
}

class Override1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x obj1 = new x();
        x obj2 = new y();
        y obj3 = new y();
        /* y obj4 = new x(); */

        obj1.methodA();
        obj2.methodA();
        obj3.methodA();
        /* obj4.methodA(); */
    }
}
```

**Program_2 :**

```
class x {
    int a[] = new int[2];

    x() {
        a[0] = 10;
        a[1] = 20;
    }

}

class y extends x {
    int a[] = new int[10];

    y() {
        a[0] = 12000;
        a[1] = 1000;
        a[2] = 120;
    }

}

class Override2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x obj1 = new x();
        x obj2 = new y();
        // y obj3 = new x();
        y obj4 = new y();
        System.out.println(obj1.a[1]);
        System.out.println(obj2.a[1]);
        System.out.println(obj4.a[1]);

    }
}
```

My specific question is that in Program_1 by what means **MethodA** of **class Y** Called? and in program_2 by What means **'20' (a[1])** of **class X** is called?

please clear my basic concept about creation of object regarding memory allotment and reference assignment.

Comment: Can you please provide output as well ?

Comment: you cannot override a variable in java but you can override a method

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question than *please clear my basic concept about creation of object regarding memory allotment and reference assignment*.

Comment: i am beginner brother.Don't have enough Reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no data polymorphism in Java.

In the first example, `methodA` is the same method implemented in different classes.

In the second example, the two `a` are completely separate, unrelated data members (even though they happen to have the same name and data type).

The second example is equivalent to:

```
class x {
    int a_x[] = new int[2];
    x() {
        a_x[0] = 10; a_x[1] = 20; 
    }

}
class y extends x {
    int a_y[] = new int[10];
    y() {
        a_y[0] = 12000; a_y[1] = 1000; a_y[2] = 120;
    }
}

class Override2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x obj1 = new x();
        x obj2 = new y();
        y obj4 = new y();
        System.out.println(obj1.a_x[1]);
        System.out.println(obj2.a_x[1]);
        System.out.println(obj4.a_y[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: got it.variable goes out of scope once inclosing brackets are closed...so another variable will have different properties although having same same name...but its not the same in methods...nice explanation...thanks

Answer (score 0):

**My specific question is that in Program_1 by what means MethodA of class Y Called?** --> Its called *Dynamic Dispatch* mechanism (Method overriding). check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). Here, the method of the RHS (instance type) is called irrespective of the reference on the LHS (child / parent), provided the parent defines the same method.

**What means '20' (a[1]) of class X is called** --> depends on the type of reference. If reference is of `X` x.field is called irrespctive of RHS.